# Unable to import moviepy module

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, moviepy

So I'm trying to import moviepy.editor and I keep getting errors, I'm new to python so if the answer is obvious I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Here's my code:

```
import os
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips

print("Program Started\n")
```

When I ever I run it I get [this error](https://pastebin.com/raw/zBCK1LR5).

When I remove `from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips` though, it doesn't give me an error.

Comment: Presumably doing `import numpy` in your program raises the same error?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code or errors. Copy and paste so that it is indexable/searchable and so that we can copy-paste it ourselves

Comment: I added text instead of an image, I tried importing numpy and got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is an bug with numpy, by doing `pip uninstall numpy` and uninstalling numpy and then reinstalling the previous version by doing `pip install numpy==1.19.3` my code started working again.