# No module named 'moviepy.editor'; 'moviepy' is not a package

Tags: python, numpy, python-import, moviepy

After reading [Unable to import moviepy module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65134573/unable-to-import-moviepy-module) and trying the answer, it didn't work for me.

I am unable to make use moviepy module. Here's my code;

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips

clip1_name: str = 'clip1.mp4'

clip1 = VideoFileClip(clip1_name)
processed_video = concatenate_videoclips([clip1])y
processed_video.write_videofile("processedVideo.mp4")
```

And below is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Tweeter\moviepy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Tweeter\moviepy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moviepy.editor'; 'moviepy' is not a package
```

I make use of Python 3.11 and moviepy version is 1.0.3.

Comment: It looks like you called your own file "moviepy.py". Now you import your file and not the package.

Comment: It skipped my mind I gave the Python file the same name as the module. Thank you @Matthias